# Как добавить второй язык на свой сайт?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть сайт на русском языке. Нужно сделать чтобы с помощью 2-х кнопок (ru, en) была возможность менять язык на английский и обратно. 
Вот сам сайт www.dvacine.by . Он состоит из меню, которое переключает между отдельными html - страницами.
Думаю, есть какой-то вариант с переменными, но не могу сам сделать все грамотно. 
Прошу подробный ответ, т.к. сам чайник)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классический вариант состоит в том, что вы всю статику, то есть слова вроде "Главная", "О нас", "Контакты" и т.д. сохраняете в словарь. Словарем может быть просто массив строк, может какой нибудь xml файл - как угодно и как вам удобнее. Можно хранить словарь и БД, но тогда надо будет его оттуда и получать каждый раз.

Например, вы заводите массивы словарей, где-нибудь в начале обработки запроса от пользователя:

```
$rus = array('Main' => 'Главная', 'About' => 'О нас', 'Contacts' => 'Контакты');
$eng = array('Main' => 'Main', 'About' => 'About', 'Contacts' => 'Contacts');
```

Потом, при обработке запроса вы смотрите какой язык вам нужно выдать - тут уж как пожелаете - можно куки ставить, но лучше просто в url добить ru или eng, чтобы понимать какой язык пользователь выбрал. 
Соответсвенно потом выбираете нужный словарь в какую нибудь абстрактную переменную (можно сразу ей и присваивать, не надо кучу массивов создавать) типа так

```
$dict = $rus; // или $dict = $eng
```

И после не пишите

```
<?php echo 'О нас'; ?>
```

А пишите в любом случае

```
<?php echo $dict['About']; ?>
```

Такой способ позволяет абстрагироваться от языка и легко добавить новые языки, когда понадобиться, не исправляя основного кода.

---

**Пример**

Пусть в файле `lang.php` определны словри `$rus` и `$eng` - лучше их вообще говоря определять не как глобальные переменные, а например как статические свойства класса - чтобы они никуда не затерялись потом по в коде.

И пусть все запросы проходят через `index.php` - то есть это точка входа программы, тогда можно сделать так.

Файл `lang.php`

```
class LangDicts {
  public static $rus = array('Main' => 'Главная', 'About' => 'О нас', 'Contacts' => 'Контакты');
  public static $eng = array('Main' => 'Main', 'About' => 'About', 'Contacts' => 'Contacts');
  public static $dict; // текущий словарь
}
```

Потом в файле `index.php` делаем следующее

```
require \filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT') . 'lang.php';
// далее некоторая логика выбора языка и например мы выбираем русский
LangDicts::$dict = LangDicts::$rus;
```

Потом везде в разных файлах  вместо

```
<?php echo 'О нас'; ?>
```

надо будет писать

```
<?php echo LangDicts::$dict['About']; ?>
```

Вообще еще можно использовать пространства имен, чтобы избежать возможных конфликтов. Да и чтобы сократить код можно в начале файла присваивать словать локальной переменной:

```
<?php $d = LangDicts::$dict['About']; ?>

<!-- тут всякий код, но убедитесь, что $d не переприсваивается, иначе лучше использовать полный вариант -->

<?php echo $d['About']; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Однако есть большая просьба расписать все подробнее, т.к. я не программист и делаю сам себе сайт по скачанной заготовке. Принцип по которому смена языков должна работать, я понимаю. Но технически сделать это не получилось. Есть кнопка для переключения языков, а дальше не понятно, какая должна быть в ней ссылка, нужно ли создавать отдельный php файл и как его подключить. Сами переменные должны прописываться просто вместо текста и т.д. Если это реально объяснить)

Comment: @DmitryLevkovsky  Я предполагал, что вы делаете сайт вручную и можете все поменять. По сути дела - надо будет отредактировать все места где выводится текст. Если вы можете их все отредактировать - то я уже все написал и даже показал как массивы завести, и выводить вместо текста элементы массива. Если вы можете создать 2 массива, то вы также можете по умолчанию попробавать вывести каждый  (то есть просто в коде выбрать один из них) - язык должен смениться. Вообщем для начала - создайте оба массива, и выводите везде значения одного из них. Если это сделано - напишите тут мне

Comment: Да, код редактирую вручную. <?php echo $dict['About']; ?> это надо прописывать в html вместо текста ссылки? Я создал файл, lang.php, который находится в папке php в корне сайта. В этом файле у меня прописаны массивы словарей, как в вашем примере и больше ничего там нет. Что дальше? Я так полагаю, что в этот php файл надо дописать механизм, по которому будет определяться язык, вбиваться в юрл и заноситься в куки? Спасибо

Comment: @DmitryLevkovsky добавил пример для вас в ответ. Попробуйте все сделать, и потом в ручную поставить разные словари - то русский `LangDicts::$dict = LangDicts::$rus;` то английский `LangDicts::$dict = LangDicts::$eng;` - язык должен меняться.

Comment: У меня нет файла index.php,  его надо создать?(есть только lang.php и contacts.php с формой обратной связи) А есть только index.html и другие html. страницы типа контакты, о нас и т.д, где находиться весь текст, который надо менять. Ссылка, например на пункт меню выглядит так `<a href="#home.html" data-path-href="html/home/">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>` но если я меняю `ГЛАВНАЯ` на  `<?php echo LangDicts::$dict['About']; ?>` то у меня пропадает этот текст  вообще. Где моя ошибка?

Comment: я, кстати, пробую это делать прямо на сайте в интернете, на примере слова ГЛАВНАЯ, поэтому, если что, то там сразу можно посмотреть код

Comment: @DmitryLevkovsky ну это тогда пробема я скажу - то есть у вас вообще по сути то нет php файлов и весь сайт сделан просто в статическом html? Это ваш сайт http://www.dvacine.by ?  Если да - то у вас все подтягивается через js - то есть вся логика на клиенте (и если выключить js - то вообще сайт не грузится), а это уже вовсе другая песня. Я конечно могу дать общие рекомендации как все надо переделать, но боюсь что без помощи специалиста тут вам не разобраться - по сути надо изменить структуру сайта, чтобы контент отдавался через php, а не в статическом виде. Либо переписывать логику javascript'a